# Why toDouble method is not working ? in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thsSo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWVC3.png)
...

Comment: Seems to work just fine. What is the problem?

Comment: is it should be 55.0 ?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double values are not printed with zeroes after the decimal point if those zeros have no mathematical importance.

Printing 55.0 will just print "55". That is to quote the documentation:

> The representation is a number literal such that the closest double value to the representation's mathematical value is this double.

In other words, "55" is the simplest form of "55.0" there is. Mathematically, you could also say it's "55.00" or "55.000" or even "55.00000000000". It doesn't change.

Comment: I added second photo. Can you look it? working there. thanks for answer but I still have questions :)

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code. There is no way to copy/paste from pictures and no way for search engines to index this, so nobody will be able to find it.

Comment: You example: `void main() { int i = 42; double d = i.toDouble(); print(d); }` prints "42" for me.

Comment: okay, thanks for help